# yii PDO.php error: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, yii, pdo, amazon-ec2

So i have been trying to move my yii project from my local to an ec2 server.  I am currently running into this error:

http://ec2-54-69-72-155.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/www/index.php

I have checked online, and i made a PHP info file that displays this : http://ec2-54-69-72-155.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/www/phpinfo_test.php

I have tried re installing/updating and it's up to date.

My database connection looks like this:

```
'db'=>array(
                'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename',
                'emulatePrepare' => true,
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => 'password',
                'charset' => 'utf8',
            ),
```

Anyone that could shed some light on this would be nice.  Thank you.

Comment: You must install / enable / compile pdo and pdo_(your db engine) on your server

Comment: Sorry, i am new to server and linux, any idea how to do that?

Comment: What Linux distribution do you have on your server? (please provide all details, for example architecture, if you have Cpanel, etc)

Comment: I am using amazon linux base, but i think i got it.  It was a restart apche issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like neither php-pdo nor php-mysql extensions are available on your EC2 machine.

Since PDO class is usually available as soon as the extension is loaded, yii is confused and tries to find it as PDO.php - which it will never find :).

Answer (score 0):

### CentOS / Fedora / RedHat

`yum install php-pdo`

### Debian / Ubuntu

`apt-get install php-pdo`